# Download html page and images

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to copy an image from an html page, just one image of the page. The point is that this a captcha image and I need to get it without making a new request.

What is the best way to do this?

I'm using httpwebrequest in c# to do this, but always need to make two requests: one to get the image name and another to download the image.

And the captcha is updated every request.

Comment: You can't. One request = one response. Each linked resource (images, JS etc) is a separate request in the background.

Comment: Image name you should already have from HTML source of the page you downloaded, why do u need another request for that?

Comment: So, in fact I have the image name, but there is somheting like 'captcha.aspx'. For each request an image is updated

Comment: In addiction, There are a couple an information that I have to copy in html...